File not recognized and recipe for target error in the BUSMASTER
I have got the error while building the node. The error is File not recognized and also recipe for target ABS_ECU failed error, Can anyone help me to get out from the error?
D:\BUSMASTER\Configurations\ABS_ECU.cpp 
C:\ProgramData\BUSMASTER\General\DBCache\CE7D_gcc10.3.0.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe: *** (ABS_ECU.dll] Error 1
D:\BUSMASTER\Configurations\ABS_ECUmake:19: recipe for target 'ABS_ECU.d11' failed
Error in creating D:\BUSMASTER\Configurations\ABS_ECU.d11 

I don't know what to do



Try to exclude . And - in your path.

Uninstall Mingw and install properly
Busmaster -> Help -> Additional installation
Follow the procedure


